# Axioms of Propositional Logic with as few negation axioms as possible

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus

Could you direct me to an axiom system for propositional logic over the connectives $\land$, $\lor$, and $\lnot$ with as few axioms over negation as reasonably possible? I've done a fair bit of googling and what comes up seems non-minimal.

I'm not expecting something provably minimal, just some suggestions that are more elegant than most of what's out there.

Comment: Can you give an example of "what's out there" and why it is not minimal enough? The most common Hilbert-style systems only have one axiom involving negation, and if negation is primitive, you certainly need at least one axiom involving it. And there are a good many systems where negation isn't primitive, so it doesn't appear at all. Or there are systems that just have no axioms whatsoever, though if negation is primative it will have to appear in some rule of inference.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: thanks for writing. [This one](https://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/progteori/ht12/Axiom.pdf) seemed typical: it had DeMorgan's laws as well as a double-negation law that seemed provable from the other axioms. Then the [list of Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) didn't seem to provide a system based on the desired connectives. These remarks are based on quick readings; I may be missing something obvious. Finally, thanks to your notes, I need to clarify that I prefer that negation be treated as an axiom...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: ...as an axiom, not a rule of inference.

Comment: The Hilbert systems just don't need the other connectives... $\to$ and $\lnot$ form a complete set, so $\land$ and $\lor$ can be defined in terms of them: $A\land B:= \lnot(A\to \lnot B)$ and $A\lor B := \lnot A\to B.$ There is always a tradeoff between minimality and intuitiveness, e.g. look at Meredith's systems... that's a full system of PL... it can prove everything the 2 page document you linked can. (I for one don't see much of a point in minimality outside a few technical contexts.)

Comment: So I can just rewrite, say, the third Łukasiewicz system as you suggest and still get a complete propositional deductive system? How about a system that includes only DeMorgan's laws for negation? Will that be complete?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a system that includes only DeMorgan's laws for negation. Note that the equational system in the file you link is a somewhat different way of going about things than the Hilbert-style with only statements and no equations. Yes, the third system there is complete in the sense that it can prove any propositional tautology, but I don't know what rewrite I suggested. (Incidentally the first system seems incomplete to me).

Comment: Hilbert's axiom list (the one listed on the page) is really intuitive if you know the motivation behind it.  But you are asking about $\land \lor \lnot$ and not $\to \lnot$ so I can't really explain why here.  So for your question, it would help if you explain whether you want fewer characters axioms, or whether you want most obvious to use axioms.

Comment: If you have the negation sign as primitive, [a single axiom using $\lnot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_negation) is enough (in addition to the axiom for $\to$).

Comment: Aletrnatively, you can use $\bot$ as primitive (defining $\lnot A$ as $A \to \bot$) in which case, again, a [single additional axiom with $\bot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_falsum) is enough.

Comment: We can't just use definitions to rewrite axioms using other connectives, because then the definitions would play an essential part in the system.  For example, from axioms that use 'C' and 'N' (I'm using Polish notation) all C-N theorems can get derived.  But, if we translate the 'C' axioms to those involving 'A' and 'N', then we can't derive all 'A' and 'N' theorems, even if we use A-N modus ponens.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: sorry about my lack of precision. By "a system that includes only DeMorgan's laws for negation" I mean that no other axiom in the system contains a negation symbol. As for the rewrite you suggested, I mean for example: $A \land B := \lnot(A \rightarrow \lnot B)$.

Comment: @DanielV: Thanks for the clarifying comment. I'm not looking for fewer characters per se, I'm more interested in axioms that are easy to use.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thanks for writing. Yes, as I understand it, for the $\lnot, \rightarrow$ systems, there exist axiom systems with one axiom for $\lnot$. Does there exist a system over the standard connectives in my question where there is a single axiom for $\lnot$, where no other axiom even mentions the $\lnot$ symbol?

Comment: @ShyPerson Are you aware that you can't actually have a system of logic with just axioms?  You need at least 1 rule of inference.

Comment: @DanielV: yes: modus ponens is fine.

Comment: @ShyPerson You want to modus ponens without an implication operator?

Comment: @DanielV: I'll make an exception for it since it's a rule of inference.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use Polish notation.  We don't need both A, and K, since both {A, N} and {K, N} form a complete set of connectives.  Here's three A-N systems with a single axiom... all of them have {AN$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$ as their rule of inference in addition to uniform substitution.

1. ANANANpqArAstANANspArAtp.
2. ANANANpqArAstANANtsArAps.
3. ANANANpqArAstANANrpAtAsp.

All of these come from C. A. Meredith's 1953 paper on single axioms, referenced from A. N. Prior's *Formal Logic* p. 305, 1962, 2nd edition.